# how to send data between two iOS devices not on same network

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know if there is a way to send data between two iOS devices not on the same network using a unique code generated by one device and entered into the other. If not what is the best way to do something similar to something like this in Swift.

Comment: If the devices are next to each other then research into bluetooth. If they are far apart you will have to implement a server as a go between.

Comment: Are the devices physically near to each other, or geographically far apart?  Is the user expected to manually share the data, or should it happen in the background transparently without any user intervention?  If nearby with user intervention, you can use AirDrop which will use Bluetooth and Wi-Fi to create a temporary, protected and encrypted network between the two devices and then automatically tear it down again as soon as the data transfer is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two devices are not close, you will have to use Server side to handle this. Try using Firebase https://firebase.google.com/
If they are close to each other, you must use AirDrop.

I recommend to use Firebase, it is really simple and well documented.

Comment: You can use AirDrop between two devices that are not on the same area network?

Comment: Yes.  AirDrop will create its own network between the two devices (they have to be close enough for this to work, and it requires bluetooth and wifi).  The network is closed to other devices and all traffic is encrypted.  The network is deleted once the data transfer is complete.

Comment: Thanks I will check out firebase.